# get value of multi dimensional array

Tags: php

My answer should be `tran2`, `tran3`, `tran4` if `name = transport_method`

ex:-

```
Array ( 
   [0] => Array ( [name] => transport_method[] [value] => tran2 ) 
   [1] => Array ( [name] => transport_method[] [value] => tran3 ) 
   [2] => Array ( [name] => transport_method[] [value] => tran4 ) 
)
```

Comment: Can you format that code, please? And post the code you already have?

Comment: you want to print?? or you want a array of value??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply [foreach()](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) with your desired condition check using `if()`

```
foreach($array as $arr){
  if($arr['name'] =='transport_method[]'){
    echo $arr['value'];
   }
}
```

***Please check all the three outputs:-*** https://eval.in/939902   And  https://eval.in/939909  And  https://eval.in/939911

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    foreach($yourvariable as $data) {
      if($data['name'] == "transport_method"){
      echo $data['value'];
    }
}
```